# Dagger-Android: Unable to inject adaper that contains an interface

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to inject my custom recycler adapter in my fragment. The adapter holds an interface (`ClickHandler`) that my fragment implements. However, I can't figure out how to inject the interface. The below is how I'm trying to inject it.

**This is how I'm trying to inject my `ClickHandler` interface:**

```
@Module
public abstract class StreamsFragmentModule
{
    @Binds
    abstract ClickHandler bindStreamsFragment(StreamsFragment streamsFragment);

    @Provides 
    static ClickHandler bindClickHandler(StreamsFragment streamsFragment)
    {
        return streamsFragment;
    }
}
```

**This is how I'm using/defining the adapter:**

```
public class StreamsFragment extends RecyclerFragment
{
    @Inject
    RecyclerViewBindingAdapter<BaseViewModel> bindingAdapter;
}

public abstract class RecyclerFragment extends Fragment implements ClickHandler
{
    public static class RecyclerViewBindingAdapter<T extends BaseViewModel> extends RecyclerView
    .Adapter<RecyclerViewBindingAdapter.BindingViewHolder>
{
        private final ClickHandler clickHandler;
        private List<T> viewModels;

        @Inject
        public RecyclerViewBindingAdapter(ClickHandler clickHandler)
        {
            this.clickHandler = clickHandler;
        }
}
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
AppComponent.java:17: error: [Dagger/DependencyCycle] Found a dependency cycle:
public interface AppComponent
   ^
  ClickHandler is injected at
      RecyclerFragment.RecyclerViewBindingAdapter(clickHandler)
  RecyclerFragment.RecyclerViewBindingAdapter<BaseViewModel> is injected at
      StreamsFragment.bindingAdapter
  StreamsFragment is injected at
      StreamsFragmentModule.bindClickHandler(streamsFragment)
  ClickHandler is injected at
      RecyclerFragment.RecyclerViewBindingAdapter(clickHandler)
  RecyclerFragment.RecyclerViewBindingAdapter<BaseViewModel> is injected at
      StreamsFragment.bindingAdapter
  FavoritesFragment is injected at
      dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [AppComponent → ActivityBindingModule_ContributeMainActivityInjector.MainActivitySubcomponent → MainActivityModule_ContributeFavoritesFragmentInjector.FavoritesFragmentSubcomponent]
```

Hopefully I've provided enough information. I'd be happy to update with more code if needed. I'm new to Dagger 2 so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using Dagger for this. Simply create the `RecyclerViewBindingAdapter` yourself in the `StreamsFragment` and pass in `this` as the `ClickHandler`.

```
RecyclerViewBindingAdapter<BaseViewModel> adapter = new RecyclerViewBindingAdapter(this);
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain why we can't use Dagger 2 for this?